# Live Stream: Storing, Transcoding, Restreaming

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, storage, transcoding

I'm currently working on a project where I have the following use case regarding video streaming:

```
1) receive live video stream (mkv container would be prefered)
2) store this stream (on cloud storage)
3) optionally transcode the stream into mp4/etc.
4) optionally store the transcoded stream (on cloud storage)
5) re-transmit transcoded stream
```

All those process steps should be performed in real-time (as I'm dealing with a live stream) and if possible simultaneously (storing of incoming stream, transcoding + rebroadcasting)

Are there any commercial/open source solutions that are able to do just that? This server would be running in the cloud under a linux VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out kaltura http://www.kaltura.org/project .. I haven't used it but they should have something.

If you are looking at building your own then ffmpeg (for transcoding and muxing) and gstreamer(as a framework) can be of very good help.

You may also need to consider what all streaming protocols you are planning to support to ingest and stream out video.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks Swaroop! I also found services like livestream and video cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Flumotion: http://flumotion.net/

Open source solution, based on GStreamer, and already has all the pieces you need (I'm not sure there's an official way to stream .mkv, but Flumotion handles .webm so it shouldn't be hard to make it work)

Disclaimer: I'm a Flumotion developer.